# Magento 2: How to set meta description/keywords with observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, tags

I need to `generate` `meta` `tags` for the page based on its data.

I succeeded in doing that by `overriding` one of the `blocks` & `changing` the `page config` object during `_prepareLayout()`, but I'm not so happy with that & prefer to use an `observer` instead.

The thing is I don't know what event to listen for, any idea?

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried a few `events` & found out that `'view_block_abstract_to_html_before'` is working for my case (unless someone has a better idea).

Comment: any specific page or all of them?

Comment: In this case, it's a category page, but I need to know how to do that for all pages.

Comment: Update: I tried a few events & found out that 'view_block_abstract_to_html_before' is working for my case (unless you have a better idea). Thanks.

Comment: can you show an example how you done this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
I tried a few events & found out that 'view_block_abstract_to_html_before' is working for my case (unless someone has a better idea).

Comment: can you show example how you done it?

Comment: You need to listen to the event `view_block_abstract_to_html_before` & then on your observer, add `\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config` to your constructor & then you can call `setKeywords`/`setDescription` on that.

Comment: setKeywords/setDescription HOw does this work i have added the constructor but not sure about "setKeywords/setDescription"

Comment: just call those methods on the pageConfig instance.

Comment: $this->pageConfig->setDescription('bla bla');

Comment: public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->config->setDescription('bla bla');
        return $this;
    }
Like this?

Comment: Its working but this effect on all the pages

Comment: Yes, of course you'll have to add your own logics in there, to check if/what to set on each page (you can get the current category/product from the registry, etc...)

Comment: its a custom page i am trying to do

Comment: OK, so you'll have to add logics to detect when the current page is your page before you change the description

Comment: Also, if it's completely custom & you have a controller for this page, you should probably do that from the controller.

Comment: the controller didnt work so this was my last solution

Comment: i am checking the url if the url is what i wanted to show the description